# Rails: Mysql query returning null

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a Rider table with their cities. I am extracting entries matching to current user's city from database.

This is what i am writing in controller:

```
@riders = Rider.where("city = ?", current_user.profile.location.split(",")[1] )
```

But it is retuning null as if nothing matches to "current_user.profile.location.split(",")[1]"

If the value of "current_user.profile.location.split(",")[1]" is "New York" and if i replace "current_user.profile.location.split(",")[1]" with "New York" in above query, it returns users matching to New York.

I am not getting why thing is happening.

Can anybody help?

Comment: What query do you see in `log/development.log`?

Comment: @tadman hmmm. I see this: `riders` WHERE (city = ' New York'). I guess space before new is not matching entries. How to remove this space?

Comment: @tadman solved. Did this: current_user.profile.location.split(",")[1].lstrip. Thanks

Comment: You should add that as an answer if it solved your problem. You could also `split(/,\s*/)` to eat the space as part of the split operation.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. 
It was taking space before city_name and hence was not able to match with Database entries.

Did this:

```
 current_user.profile.location.split(",")[1].lstrip
```